# Why doesnt android View implement ViewParent while its child ViewGroup does?

Tags: java, android, oop

ViewGroup extends View and implements ViewParent,
however View has all the same functions as ViewParent has, like getParent(), etc.

Is it better if View implements ViewParent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The View is the basic building block of UI components. Thus it can be anything and widget , a layout.
- ViewGroup is the base class for layouts and views containers.
- ViewParent interface defines the responsibilities for a class that will be a parent of a View.

If we consider these 3 points then it seems more logically correct if ViewGroup implements ViewParent.ViewGroup will be used by all views which have children. Thus ViewParent interfaces fits correctly here